# Cannot log in to MacBook after keyboard went crazy

Tags: macbook, login

so, here's the likely scenario: I took my macbook out of the backpack and opened it up after about 16 hours.  Battery is quite full still.  Also pulled out my wireless logitech keyboard which was "on" and that wound up typing quite a few characters in the password entry field.

I noticed this and cleared out all of the characters, entered my normal password, and it now won't accept the password, and I can't log in.

This is NOT a caps lock issue; I've verified it's off.

Is there any failed-tries-count timeout on a MacBook?  I don't know.

Any ideas? Certainly the keyboard could have hit "enter" several times as I was pulling it out of the mess in my backpack.  But certainly couldn't have logged in and reset the password :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try power off (even forcefully) and try booting again.
You got a macbook, so please try entering password by the keyboard on the laptop.

If it doesn't work, you can try Single user mode when you're locked out. This requires your hard drive not encrypted.

[See official support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)

[A solution to recover password using single user mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/61905)